# What is "namespace clt and dmp"?

Tags: c++, vector, namespaces

I'm trying to implement a vector in c++.

Found this online: http://doingmyprogramming.com/2013/06/25/implementing-a-vector-in-c-working-smarter-not-harder/

I'm confused as to what namespace clt & namespace dmp are.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are [namespaces](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace). In this case, they are structured this way:

```
global
    -> clt
        -> dmp
```

If you look few lines lower, you will see this code:

```
namespace clt {
namespace dmp {

template <typename T>
class vector {

..words..

};
}
}
```

It defines class `vector<T>` inside namespace `dmp`, which is itself defined inside namespace `clt`. So, when you are in global namespace (let's say, `main()` function), you must use explicit scope operator to be able to use `vector`. Example:

```
int main()
{
    clt::dmp::vector<int> vecint; //Create vector of ints

    //...
}
```

The most common example of a namespace is `namespace std`, which contains C++ standard library primitives.

Oh, and if you are concerned about their names (`clt` and `dmp`) - they are probably just abbreviations.

Comment: In main, could I type using namespace clt like std? I haven't seen this before. Also, do clt and dmp stand for anything or are they just arbitrary names (as opposed to some c++ convention I dont know about)? Thanks!

Comment: They are just arbitrary names, that author introduced for some reason. And yes, you can use `using` declaration/directive just like in case of `std` namespace.